# IBM server x3550 M Hard Disk Issue

Tags: ibm-xseries

Recently, I've bought this used system. I've purchased two HDD 74 GB and 146GB.

When the system loads, in the BIOS it shows both hard disk detected.

While CENTos 6.6 installation it is showing 74GB HDD only. 146GB is totally missing from the DISK. What can be the issue ?

Comment: Comment instead of an answer since I don't have specifics for you. IBM x-series servers have RAID controllers, so before you boot/install your operating system, you need to check the RAID configuration. Best guess is that the RAID controller is set for RAID-1 and it set your two drives up as a mirrored pair. You can do this with drives of different sizes, you just lose the extra space on the larger drive. If this is the case and you want separate drives, you probably need to set up two RAID-0 disks, each with one of your disks.

Comment: okay, I'm trying with Raid controller setup.